# Should I use "did" in the following question?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

> What (did) scared(scare) him more? If his date wanted to be serious or if she
>   didn't?

Do I need a *did* there? Why or why not?

Comment: Actually it should be; Which scared him more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can phrase your first sentence in either of two ways; either "What scared him more?" or "What did scare him more?".

Both sentences are grammatical and very close to each other in meaning, but "What did scare him more" implies he is no longer scared, while "What scared him more" doesn't imply if he is still currently scared or not.